# Converting speech to text in iOS

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a sample example which implements open ear or any other speech recognizer to convert speech into text. Is there any tutorial which can help me out with the text to speech conversion.

Comment: No tutorial, but here's [my easy-to-use library](http://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec) that works on iOS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use your library and what method calls I need to use to implement the functionality

Comment: [Here is](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec/blob/master/examples/simple.c) the most minimalistic example possible.

Comment: Its in C language I'm looking for something in Obj-C

Comment: It works fine in Objective-C since Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

Comment: OpenEars developer here. You can follow the customizable OpenEars tutorial at http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial or download and run the OpenEars sample app (called OpenEarsSampleApp.xcodeproj) which is in the OpenEars distribution downloadable at http://www.politepix.com/openears

Answer (score 4):

There are several libraries for speech to text coversion. You can use any of them.

They are as below :

1. [openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) This is the best library for this.
2. [libsprec](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec)
   This uses the Google speech recognition APIs, so it supports multiple languages.
3. [VocalKit](https://github.com/H2CO3/VocalKit) which uses the high-quality opensource PocketSphinx library (however, it currently supports English only).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Can you tell how to use libsprec? I mean how can I integrate it in my xcode project?