# How to create Speech To UITextField Without using the keyboard option but by using a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, speech

On the iPhone YouTube app when you search for anything there is a `button/UIButton` at the side of a `UITextField` that allows you to speak and it converts it to text without using the keyboard options. My client is asking for the same functionality but not sure how to implement this. Can anyone tell me what I'm looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367018/converting-speech-to-text-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something yourself will take years to implement. You have to get help from any third parties

Basically you need a speech to text conversion library

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec

https://github.com/H2CO3/VocalKit

http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/pocketsphinx/

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/

https://www.ispeech.org/developers

Probably any one of this will give you some idea

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any public api for do it (except opposite function tts), some people say to use external speech to text library such as OpenEars (is an open-source library for speech to text conversion for iPhone and iPad see: http://www.politepix.com/openears). 
Maybe it could help you

Answer (score 0):

You need a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`.

When the UIButton has been 'touched up inside' you should call a method to update the UI with some kind of progress/feedback indicator.

Simultaneously you should invoke use of the microphone and record the users speech.

Then using **Fourier analysis** or some other method you need to analyse the speech and convert to text.

Finally set the textLabel on the `UITextField` with the converted text from the previous step.

Comment: This is far more complicated then describing it in few lines... What I mean is that without a library, doing it from scratch requires a lot of work and knowledge in this field

Comment: That might actually work. In fact I did something similar, when I wanted to travel to the moon last year: I just built a space rocket, using sheet metal and lots of fuel. Catched a cold on moon, though.

Comment: @Toastor haha ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer. Obviously the OP's issue is beyond the scope of a single question :)

Comment: @JohnWoods Don't worry, I couldn't agree with you more ;)